# Does "You have a surprise coming" mean "You have a surprise for somebody" or "Somebody has a surprise for you"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

[stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/339427/about-inversion-and-exclamations):
**(1)** *Have you got a surprise coming!*
I don't understand what (1) means.

To simplify it, let's rewrite it this way:
**(2)** *You have a surprise coming*.

Does (2) mean (3) or (4)?:
**(3)** *You have a surprise for somebody*.
**(4)** *Somebody has a surprise for you*.

Comment: When someone has *a surprise coming*, or [*a disappointment coming*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22got+a+disappointment+coming%22), or [*a treat in store*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22got+a+treat+in+store%22), it's always coming / in store ***for them.*** They're not planning to surprise, disappoint, or treat ***you*** - but usually they're not planning *anything* (they don't know what's going to happen to them).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you're right about the OP's case with "coming", but to have something "in store" can also be used about the person who's planning it: "*...she gaily took his arm and said that she had a surprise in store for him...*"

Comment: @gotube: You're quite right, and actually [the same applies with 'coming'](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+had+a+surprise+coming+for+him%22). But in both your example and mine, the context couldn't be clearer. Firstly, because the (female) person actually *says* they have a surprise "pending", and secondly because both examples include ***for him***. Even if the "surpriser" didn't explicitly announce the impending surprise (and you can hardly surprise *yourself* in such contexts), if there was no ***for-*** clause, i would never expect the *subject* to be the "surprisee".

Comment: @FumbleFingers As far as I understood you, "_X has a surprise coming_" usually means "a surprise for X" but in a specific context can mean "X's surprise for someone else". If we remove "_coming_", does "_X has a surprise_" also mean these two meanings? Thanks.

Comment: "X has a surprise" doesn't really mean anything to me unless it's followed by "coming, instore,..." and/or "for Y". Context is everything.

Answer (score 2):

It means that someone else has a surprise planned for you. The surprise is coming to you. It is not that you are planning a surprise for someone else.

"Coming" means "toward the person or place under discussion". If I said, "Bob is coming to America", that means that Bob is presently somewhere other than America but that he plans to arrive in America. If I wanted to say that he was leaving America, I would say, "Bob is going from America."

So "you have a surprise coming" means that the surprise is coming to you, not going from you to someone else.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your explanation. In your example "_Bob is coming to America_" there is "_to America_" after "_coming_", which does the sense understandable. But in "_You have a surprise coming_" there is nothing after "_coming_" so unfortunately the analogy doesn't work because it's not written to whom a surprise comes.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to add clarity and maybe I just made it more confusing. "Coming" in general implies coming "to here", wherever we are. We sometimes add a "to PLACE" to say how specific the place is. Like do I mean, "to this building", "to this country", "to this planet", or exactly what? But if we are, say, in the United States, I would NOT say, "Bob is coming to France." I would say "Bob is going to France."